# CF10 concatenated mysql string as binary data

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm working on moving a site from CF8 to CF10 and just came across something I wasn't expecting.  My MySQL query has a simple concatenate to combine a company ID with company name as such:

```
SELECT CONCAT(co_coid, ' - ',co_company) AS IDCONAME
```

On CF8, this returns a string I can just as my display value on a cfselect.

```
998 - Company A
999 - Company B
```

etc.

However, on CF10 when I dump the query it's showing as binary data and I have to use toString() on the output.

I knew there were some gotchas that required using toString() when returning encrypted data that weren't there before, but I'm not sure why it's doing this on a simple string concatenation.

[update]
Can this be changed through a connect string or other server wide setting?  I know I can use toString() on output, or CAST() in the query, but something server wide would be ideal.  The MySQL server is the same server, so there's no version change there.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns? The [mySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) say this is the expected behavior with certain data types. (Edit) AFAIK, you cannot change this other than using a CAST as JW mentioned. Since CF8 and CF10 use different drivers, there may also be driver differences as well.

Comment: This change was introduced in CF9. A number of MySQL functions will return binary unless you CAST the values as strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

convert the number into string,

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(co_coid AS CHAR(15)), ' - ',co_company) AS IDCONAME
```

Comment: Thanks - I know there are ways to handle this, but I'm more curious as to thy "why", and if there's a global fix (connect string on the DSN) that could solve this at the server level.

Comment: Your original query was less than perfect.  ColdFusion has a history of being less tolerent of this type of thing as you get to higher versions.

Comment: Thanks - it was an oldie probably leftover from CF 5 or 6.  I'll have to spend some time going through and making sure any other gotchas are addressed.